# Symfony WARNING: No configuration file (php.ini) used by PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I downloaded PHP using brew on Mac

```
# Update homebrew
brew update

# Add the tap
brew tap shivammathur/php

# Install PHP 8.0
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

But when I run

```
symfony check:req
```

I get

```
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
WARNING: No configuration file (php.ini) used by PHP!
```

**Why Symfony doesn't access php.ini file?**
Even though php.ini file exists, I checked that by:

```
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/8.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

Please consider that I am an absolute beginner in PHP
Thank You

Comment: There's a difference between CLI and server (probably Apache) contextes, create simple script in your public directory with that content `<?php phpinfo();` and visit it via web browser , to check which php.ini is loaded. You may need to specify another `PHPIniDir` in httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and i solved it by changing the name of this file.
When i installed php, i created a file php.ini. (a copy of php.ini-development that i renamed in php.ini). I modified a few lines and i installed "Composer".
But when i checked symfony requirements, i saw this problem as you.
When i opened it with VSC i noticed the file was called php.ini.ini.
I think it was "Composer" who changed the name when i installed it.
I renamed it to php.ini and I no longer had this problem.